# angularjs - load different controllers/js files based on users' access levels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, ngroute

I'm working on a web app where users have different access levels. Each access level has different sets of controllers/views.

I'm using `ngRoute` and `ng-view`. Each controller has its own JS file and it also contains the route mapping information for just that controller. Each controller looks like:

```
angular.module('MainApp', ['ngRoute'])

 .controller('ContollerX', function() {
 })

.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/ControllerXURL', {
    templateUrl: 'ViewX.html',
    controller: 'ControllerX'
  });
});
```

(Not sure if it's the best practice)

I don't want to load all the controllers upfront. Is it possible to load just the controllers a user need based on a user's access level, which is determined after he/she logs in (user access level data returned from backend)? What would be the best approach?

I'm thinking to load the controller scripts dynamically, like inserting the script tag. Will it work? Does AngularJs have any built-in function for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much easier way to achieve what you want using `resolve` property in route definition object. The `resolve` returns a promise and the route to the controller using resolve will be redirected only when this promise is resolved. You can use this to redirect to required view.

Say you have 2 views: AuthorizedUsers.html and UnauthorizedUsers.html and corresponding controllers AuthorizedUsersController and UnauthorizedUsersController. You can have your route definition for these views as below:

```
 angular
   .module('MainApp', ['ngRoute'])
   .controller('AuthorizedUsersController', function(auth) {
   })
   .controller('UnauthorizedUsersController', function() {
   })
   .config(function($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
       .when('/authorizedusers', {
         templateUrl: 'AuthorizedUsers.html',
         controller: 'AuthorizedUsersController',
         resolve: {
           auth: function ($q, $location) { 
             var defer = $q.defer();
             if (isAuthorized) {
               defer.resolve();
             } else {
               $location.path('/unauthorized');
               defer.reject();
             }
             return defer.promise;
           }
         }
       })
       .when('/unauthorizedusers', {
         templateUrl: 'UnauthorizedUsers.html',
         controller: 'UnauthorizedUsersController'
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. It's good to know. But my question is actually how to load just the needed controller files "after" the user logs in.

Comment: Does that mean you want to actually defer loading the controller definitions until the user logs in? Angular doesn't provide a way to lazily load script resources and add them to the the application. Unless you've somehow created an enormous behemoth application you would probably be better off minifying and concatenating your entire code base into a single js file (or perhaps 2 or 3). You can also compile your html template into js and have it delivered as a single cached payload. Loading stuff on demand sounds good... until u have to wait for it load

Comment: Really? I thought it was better to load the scripts on demand since a user doesn't need all of them. Thanks for the info.

Comment: BTW, since Javascript is client-side, isn't the `if (isAuthorized)` easy to be hacked? The value of `isAuthorized` can be changed locally and thus the user can view authorized pages. Is it true?

Comment: You should not rely only on client side checks while exposing resources from server. The server api check should be independent of the client side check

Comment: Regarding your other question on on-demand loading, its not always wise to do on-demand loading. The optimization is a mix of bundling & minification and on-demand loading. If you have a lot of network requests generated due to on-demand loading the user experience is bad due to wait time. Ideally yous should bundle & minify files/ modules needed initially and are frequently used and load the files which are less frequently and rarely used on-demand. Again this approach needs proper tuning based on your own needs

Comment: I see. But as described in the question, we have different access levels. That means a user only see some views/controllers but not the others at all (not even less frequently). Shouldn't I load the controller scripts based on a user's access level in this case?

Comment: You can do that but the effort to achieve on-demand loading in angular might not be worth the effort :)

Comment: So it's just not something AngularJS can do out of box. And if controller scripts are not too huge, probably just load them all upfront. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I would do